# Mongodb legacy UUID with like query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

we are using legacy java uuid (I think it's type 3) with `mongodb atlas 4.2.15`. Now we'd like to create a query where we will be able to use like against uuid. Is this somehow possible?

*example:*
we have `refstore` with `UUID('8418b678-0596-11ec-bbde-076881b30100')` and we'd like to perform search by some part of that uuid so for example like this

```
db.store.find({'refstore': /.*076881b30100.*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the aggregation pipeline's conversion to string feature and that conversion permits legacy UUIDs as input, you could  I imagine then perform a regexp match against the resulting string.

Comment: unfortunatelly we are using just find pipeline with. no idea about using `like query` for uuid there?